# Extracting/Removing/skipping Free Text from Json Files in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-data-factory

I am trying to do some source transformation in ADF where I have alot server logs in the following format:

```
#PartnerName    QA Server
#ApplicationName    T_GSPClient
#AccountName    DoNotModifyDMS
#SDK    desktop
#ClientVersion  5.1.1894.3
#InputChannel   DesktopMic
#User   JohnDoe
#NmsLogin   JohnDoe
#SessionId  7ba732d6-3445-4b16-b7e8-345fgd4f5g4
#ClientIP   209.122.69.109
#SRTechnology   S2
#SROptions  NoTextBefore
#GeneralLogLevel    Trace
#ModuleLogLevels    
#ServerDateTimeUTC  2023-07-06 15:28:33.105
{"date":"2023-07-06\t15:28:09.653","level":"TRACE","msg":"DMVAServerMessage-Initialize:{&quot;dmhMessage&quot;:{&quot;messageHeader&quot;:{&quot;messageType&quot;:&quot;unsubscribe&quot;,&quot;sessionId&quot;:&quot;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&quot;,&quot;messageId&quot;:&quot;aeb65e55-a7c0-4e96-a960-dc2a252d6b2c&quot;,&quot;transactionType&quot;:&quot;acknowledgement&quot;,&quot;clientType&quot;:&quot;ttsChannel&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;1.0&quot;,&quot;application&quot;:&quot;DesktopSDK&quot;},&quot;messageResponse&quot;:{&quot;resultCode&quot;:&quot;SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;errorMessage&quot;:&quot;The subscription id does not exist, unsubscribe did not remove an entry&quot;}}} ","traceId":"409e0d44-ad50-4f17-84c7-0521e01e11fc","spanId":"e0750e44-ad50-4f17-90a9-3b6940e0294b","resource":{"module":".NET","class":"Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.Internal.DMVA.DMVAServerMessage","function":"Initialize","line":70,"pid":26612,"thread":"[28-27280]"}}
{"date":"2023-07-06\t15:28:09.653","level":"TRACE","msg":"DMVAServerMessage-Initialize:{&quot;dmhMessage&quot;:{&quot;messageHeader&quot;:{&quot;messageType&quot;:&quot;unsubscribe&quot;,&quot;sessionId&quot;:&quot;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&quot;,&quot;messageId&quot;:&quot;aeb65e55-a7c0-4e96-a960-dc2a252d6b2c&quot;,&quot;transactionType&quot;:&quot;acknowledgement&quot;,&quot;clientType&quot;:&quot;ttsChannel&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;1.0&quot;,&quot;application&quot;:&quot;DesktopSDK&quot;},&quot;messageResponse&quot;:{&quot;resultCode&quot;:&quot;SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;errorMessage&quot;:&quot;The subscription id does not exist, unsubscribe did not remove an entry&quot;}}} ","traceId":"409e0d44-ad50-4f17-84c7-0521e01e11fc","spanId":"e0750e44-ad50-4f17-90a9-3b6940e0294b","resource":{"module":".NET","class":"Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.Internal.DMVA.DMVAServerMessage","function":"Initialize","line":70,"pid":26612,"thread":"[28-27280]"}}
{"date":"2023-07-06\t15:28:09.653","level":"TRACE","msg":"DMVAServerMessage-Initialize:{&quot;dmhMessage&quot;:{&quot;messageHeader&quot;:{&quot;messageType&quot;:&quot;unsubscribe&quot;,&quot;sessionId&quot;:&quot;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&quot;,&quot;messageId&quot;:&quot;aeb65e55-a7c0-4e96-a960-dc2a252d6b2c&quot;,&quot;transactionType&quot;:&quot;acknowledgement&quot;,&quot;clientType&quot;:&quot;ttsChannel&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;1.0&quot;,&quot;application&quot;:&quot;DesktopSDK&quot;},&quot;messageResponse&quot;:{&quot;resultCode&quot;:&quot;SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;errorMessage&quot;:&quot;The subscription id does not exist, unsubscribe did not remove an entry&quot;}}} ","traceId":"409e0d44-ad50-4f17-84c7-0521e01e11fc","spanId":"e0750e44-ad50-4f17-90a9-3b6940e0294b","resource":{"module":".NET","class":"Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.Internal.DMVA.DMVAServerMessage","function":"Initialize","line":70,"pid":26612,"thread":"[28-27280]"}}
{"date":"2023-07-06\t15:28:09.653","level":"TRACE","msg":"DMVAServerMessage-Initialize:{&quot;dmhMessage&quot;:{&quot;messageHeader&quot;:{&quot;messageType&quot;:&quot;unsubscribe&quot;,&quot;sessionId&quot;:&quot;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&quot;,&quot;messageId&quot;:&quot;aeb65e55-a7c0-4e96-a960-dc2a252d6b2c&quot;,&quot;transactionType&quot;:&quot;acknowledgement&quot;,&quot;clientType&quot;:&quot;ttsChannel&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;1.0&quot;,&quot;application&quot;:&quot;DesktopSDK&quot;},&quot;messageResponse&quot;:{&quot;resultCode&quot;:&quot;SERVER_ERROR&quot;,&quot;errorMessage&quot;:&quot;The subscription id does not exist, unsubscribe did not remove an entry&quot;}}} ","traceId":"409e0d44-ad50-4f17-84c7-0521e01e11fc","spanId":"e0750e44-ad50-4f17-90a9-3b6940e0294b","resource":{"module":".NET","class":"Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.Internal.DMVA.DMVAServerMessage","function":"Initialize","line":70,"pid":26612,"thread":"[28-27280]"}}
```

My objective is remove/skip the first free text lines and keep the other json data and then move it to another blob for further transformation. I tried source transformation with derived column but my Data Flow is still showing json format error. I also used Copy Data activity via ForEach with "enableSkipIncompatibleRow": true, it doesn't work. It only works if I just work with single file, not when I try to iterate over many files and skip/remove those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the first few lines which are not in Json format using ADF dataflow, follow the below approach.

- Take the source transformation with the delimitted source dataset . Take any column delimitter which is not part of the text.

[image]

- Here, I took the tilde `~` as column delimitter. So, the entire row is in the same column.

[image]

- Then take the **filter transformation** and give the filter on condition as, `substring(Column_name,1,1)=='{'`. This removes all the rows which do not begin with `{`.

[image]

- Then take the **sink transformation** and set the filename option to **Output to single file** and give the filename. In optimize, select **single partition**.

[image]

Here, I took sink file as delimited dataset with column delimiter as `No delimitter` and Quote character as `No quote character`.

[image]

**Data in Output file**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for these guidelines and indeed it works. Will it also work if I have to transform many files with the same transformation? Should I use the Output to Single File?

Comment: If you don't use output to Single file, source file will get split into multiple sink files.